# Alnum class in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the class `\p{Alnum}` in the regex of the Ruby language? What characters does it contain, and how does it differ from `[:alnum:]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the [rdoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html) and this [tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), the two expressions are equivalent.

They contain alphabetic and numeric characters. If only using ASCII characters, it is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. If there are non-ASCII characters, both `[:alnum:]` and `p{Alnum}` would also include things like accented characters.

Comment: Might they be different if we're not using only ASCII characters?

Comment: @MikaH.: If you grep around the C source you'll see that they both (AFAIK) end up being mapped to the same thing. Also, `'µ'` matches both `/[[:alnum]]/` and `/\p{Alnum}/` but not the ASCII-only `/\w/`.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, where can I find the C source?

Comment: @MikaH.: You can grab it from Github (https://github.com/ruby/ruby) or poke around in your `~/.rvm` directory, it might already be there.