# RegEx special characters detection failing on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, special-characters, locale

Users of my app can create hashtags in comments and image captions, these tags can include letters with special characters like `á` and `ä` for example.

To detect these characters I use the following:

```
content.scan(/\#[[:alnum:]]+/)
```

So if I have the following: `"This is a #tëst"` the regex should grab the word `tëst`. Locally it works just fine but on my server it gets cut off at the t before the ë and ignores the rest of the word. Any idea why this is? or how I can make a regex that works both on development and production without issue?

Comment: Your server might only be using ASCII characters for some reason? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13370932/2534803

Comment: How can I find it out and how can I make it grab the accented characters?

Comment: I added the `ruby` tag so this will hopefully be seen by someone who knows Ruby better than myself. You could grab the whole match to see what prints for debugging purposes, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Good luck!

Comment: Fair enough, thanks!

Comment: Another idea, try to create a small reproducible example of the problem and post and debug that.

Comment: What version of Ruby is running on the server?

Comment: 2.1.2 is the version on the server. I'm thinking it has something to do with the locale setting perhaps.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Encoding.html might help you identify differences....

Comment: Have you tried `"#tëst".scan(/#[[:alnum:]]+/)` outside your app, i.e. in irb or rails console?

Comment: @Stefan yeah, locally it works fine, in the staging and production servers is where it doesn't.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what happens if you run `"#tëst".scan(/#[\p{L}\p{N}]+/)`

Comment: Properly matches #tëst, at least in the console and development. I'll have to test tomorrow in production.

Comment: Could you show the context of your app where it happens? Like, the model, service or controller snippet where it is being filtered?